# Move the position of colorbar/ colorkeys in levelplot

Tags: r, plot, raster, levelplot

I have plotted a stack of raster using the function 'levelplot' script as below:

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
ras <- list.files("/filepath/", pattern = "\\.tif$", full=TRUE)
s <- stack(ras)
> levelplot(s, colorkey = list(space ="bottom",height=1, width=1),
names.attr=c("2011","2012","2013", "2014")))
```

[Figure of Levelplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Nc99.jpg)

The problem with the plot is that the label of x-axis label 'Longitude' overlaps with the colorbar/ colorkeys of the plot. Is it possible to move the position of colorkeys a little below the label 'Longitude'?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust this with the `vjust` parameter in the `xlab` list ...

```
levelplot(s, colorkey = list(space = "bottom", height = 1, width = 1),
            names.attr = c("2011", "2012", "2013", "2014"),
            xlab = list(label = "Longitude", vjust = -.2)))
```

---

**Before (with dummy data):**
[image]

**After:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks that works very well. I can't upvote your answer because I have less than 15 reputations. I am a newbie in SO.. ll' revert back to upvote when I have over 15 :)

Answer (score 0):

@Khaynes Answer to the question:

```
levelplot(s, colorkey = list(space = "bottom", height = 1, width = 1),
            names.attr = c("2011", "2012", "2013", "2014"),
            xlab = list(label = "Longitude", vjust = -.2)))
```

The result->
[image]
All Thanks to @Khaynes

Comment: you can accept @Khaynes' answer though :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution for this problem that adds padding around the x-axis label.
Just add this as additional argument to your levelplot() function and adjust the padding:

par.settings = list(layout.heights = list(xlab.key.padding = 1))

The source is this thread, where you can find some other ideas:

[levelplot: how to add space between colorkey and x-axis label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869727/levelplot-how-to-add-space-between-colorkey-and-x-axis-label)